# CSS: Disable the custom radio button

Tags: html, css

I have created a custom radio button by using the css . but i have a problem in this . Actually when select the radio button it's being selected.but i am unable to dis-select it .For creating the custom radio button i have created the css like this.

```
input[type="radio"]:checked:before {
content: "";
display: block;
position: relative;
top: 1px;
left: 0px;
width: 14px;
height: 14px;
border-radius: 50%;
background: rgb(255,196,0);
}
```

and html code for the custom radio button is like this..

```
<div style="width:93%;height: 39px;">   
    <div style="padding-top: 10px;width: 70%;height: 32px"><input type="radio" style="width: 15px;height: 16px"/>Wednesday</div>
</div>
```

Please help me through this . Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First of all radio button will not dis-select there will be pair of radio buttons.

Comment: Please can you describe me how can i do it correctly?

Comment: Check below answer of @Alorika

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide another `radio button` with the same `name` attribute. When a user clicks on a `radio-button`, it becomes checked, and all other `radio-buttons` with `equal name` become unchecked

Try this:

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked:before {
content: "";
display: block;
position: relative;
top: 1px;
left: 0px;
width: 14px;
height: 14px;
border-radius: 50%;
background: rgb(255,196,0);
}
```

```html
<div style="width:93%;height: 39px;">   
    <div style="padding-top: 10px;width: 70%;height: 32px">
      <input type="radio" name="day" style="width: 15px;height: 16px"/>Wednesday
      <input type="radio" name="day" style="width: 15px;height: 16px"/>Thursday
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

`Radio buttons` are used when there is a list of two or more options that are mutually exclusive and the user must select exactly one choice. In other words, clicking a non-selected radio button will deselect whatever other button was previously selected in the list.

`Checkboxes` are used when there are lists of options and the user may select any number of choices, including zero, one, or several. In other words, each `checkbox` is independent of all other `checkboxes` in the list, so checking one box doesn't uncheck the others.

Comment: It's working fine. But by this i am unable to select multiple buttons. @Alorika

Comment: if you wanna select multiple button use checkboxes why use radio button and expect it to work like a checkbox?

Comment: or else use checkbox and style to look like a radio button http://jsfiddle.net/xykPT/523/

Comment: @NehaPurwar: radio button is for selecting a single value out of all the values. check box is for selecting multiple values.

Comment: Ok thanks.actually i am recently working on checkbox.

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted if you are satisfied with the expanation

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with the code.

If you want a radio button then just name the other radio option same.

Of use checkbox for check and uncheck

```
<input type="checkbox" style="width: 15px;height: 16px"/>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/556huwhn/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(':radio').mousedown(function(e){
 var $self = $(this);
 if( $self.is(':checked') ){
 var uncheck = function(){
 setTimeout(function(){$self.removeAttr('checked');},0);
 };
 var unbind = function(){
 $self.unbind('mouseup',up);
 };
 var up = function(){
  uncheck();
  unbind();
 };
 $self.bind('mouseup',up);
    $self.one('mouseout', unbind);
 }
 });
```